# How to make 5 volts PWM form 3 volts on stm32?

Tags: pwm, c, stm32

I am generating PWM on the transistor with help STM32, PWM voltage of 3 volts, but the transistor is "fully open" somewhere on the 5 volts. How to make PWM voltage 5 volts, or are there transistors which can be opened fully at 3 volts and capable of flowing a current of about 20-25A current and 50 volts? Maybe there are another solutions to my problems that I will be very glad to hear it.

Comment: Of course there are better transistors. And parametric search tools to find them.

Comment: You may have to use one transistor to drive another, or find a transistor that can be fully opened at 3V and drive that much voltage/current.

Comment: Please supply component details and a bit more information about the load type and supply current capabilities.  The killowatt load you propose to control deserves a well designed drive circuit.

Comment: here is a circuit from another question  ... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/344210/p-channel-mosfet-as-power-switch#comment816834_344210

Answer (score 3):

You should use a **MOSFET driver chip** (or circuit) with 3.3V inputs.

Many have another supply for the gate drive- you can use something like 12V, which allows you to use a wide range of MOSFETs.

To control that kind of power, you want to switch the MOSFET smartly (quickly).

Power MOSFET gates require a lot of current to get them to switch quickly (amperes) due to the gate charge and the power dissipation in the transistors will be very high during the switching process so doing it quickly is important to avoid stressing the transistors excessively.

You should do more research- the application notes from the MOSFET and MOSFET driver chip manufacturers would be a good place to start. IRF (now Infineon) is one place.